# WP-CLI How to generate a list of posts with corresponding meta values

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, wp-cli

I created this SQL query to generate a list of posts (which I will use for a CSV Sheet)

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_content, p.post_title, pm1.meta_value as 'Amazon.com', pm2.meta_value as 'Amazon.co.uk' 

FROM wp_posts p 

LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 ON p.ID = pm1.post_id AND pm1.meta_key = 'Amazon.com'
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm2 ON p.ID = pm2.post_id AND pm2.meta_key = 'Amazon.co.uk' 

WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'
```

I'm trying to accomplish the same using WP-CLI, using 'wp list' and such, but I haven't been able to find a way list all posts with their meta fields in one row.

How can I accomplish this using WP-CLI ?

Answer (score 11):

Just figured it out.  This isn't clearly or explicitly documented at https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/list/ or elsewhere.

```
wp  post list --fields=ID,post_title,Amazon.com,Amazon.co.uk --meta_key=Amazon.com --meta_key=Amazon.co.uk
```